# Spring Boot Multiple Database giving null values from secondary database

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have configured 2 databases such that made 1 database primary. I am able to fetch the database from primary but secondary database is giving me null result. The corresponding configuration for secondary database tables is getting created in primary schema which is having empty result. Below is the code i have written.

Database configuration.

```
@Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.example.studentmanagement.datasource")
    public DataSource studentDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource=DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.example.ordermanagement.datasource")
    public DataSource orderDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource=DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I am using entitymanager factory with spring data repositories to fetch the data. Below is the primary and secondary configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.example.SpringBootMultipleDbs.Customer.Repos",entityManagerFactoryRef = "orderEntityManagerFactoryBean",
transactionManagerRef = "orderTransactionManager")
public class PrimaryConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource orderDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(orderDataSource);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.SpringBootMultipleDbs.Customer.Entities");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Map<String,Object> jpaPropertiesMap=new HashMap<>();
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect.class);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl.class);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.class);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager orderTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(orderEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

}
```

Secondary Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.example.SpringBootMultipleDbs.Department.Repos",entityManagerFactoryRef = "studentEntityManagerFactoryBean",
transactionManagerRef = "studentTransactionManager")
public class SecondaryConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean studentEntityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource studentDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(studentDataSource);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.SpringBootMultipleDbs.Department.Entities");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Map<String,Object> jpaPropertiesMap=new HashMap<>();
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect.class);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl.class);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.class);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager studentTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean studentEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(studentEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
    

}
```

Below is the spring data jpa repository class fetching me null data mapping to secondary database configuration.

```
public interface DepartmentRepo extends JpaRepository<Department,Integer> {
    
    public Department findByDeptId(Integer id); 

}
```

application.yml file

```
com:
  example:
    studentmanagement:
      datasource:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student
        username: root
        password: root123
    ordermanagement:
      datasource:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order
        username: root
        password: root123 
        
            
server:
  port: 8085
  servlet:
    context-path: /SpringBootDbs
```

Answer (score -1):

You Have to keep both configuration and configuration consumer code in different packages.
in your case as you have 2 DB's one for student Management and other for order Management, So you need to packaging hierarchy in you code as well. Your package Structure should be like below.

**com.example.orderManagement
//OrderManagement Config and all consumer code for order should be here**

**com.example.Studentmanagement
//Studentmanagement Config and all consumer code for student would be here**